# Matrix involving the central moments of a random variable

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, expectation

> Consider the matrix :
>   $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& \mu_2 \\
> 0& \mu_2& \mu_3 \\
> \mu_2& \mu_3& \mu_4 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $\mu_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ central moment of a RV X i.e. $\mu_k := E(X-E(X))^k$.
>
> Prove that:
>
> (a) $M$ has non-negative determinant.
>
> (b) $M$ is non-negative definite.
>
> (c) Generalize this result to higher dimensions.

My thoughts:

(a) I tried to break the moments to lower order moments and to obtain the result but it didn't workout.

(b) & (c) Could not come up with anything.

Comment: Can you evaluate expressions like $E(a+bX+cX^2)^2$ in terms of the given data?

Comment: Hint: The matrix is actually $$M=\begin{pmatrix} \mu_0& \mu_1& \mu_2 \\
\mu_1& \mu_2& \mu_3 \\
\mu_2& \mu_3& \mu_4 \end{pmatrix}$$ thus, assuming without loss of generality that $E(X)=0$, $M=(M_{k,\ell})$ with $$M_{k,\ell}=E(X^{k+\ell-2})$$ for every $1\leqslant k,\ell\leqslant3$, hence $M=E(Z^*Z)$ where $Z$ denotes the random line vector $$Z=(1,X,X^2)$$ Does this ring any bell?

Comment: @PhilJones have you thought about Did's hint? It reduces each part to essentially one line.

Comment: I hope this link will be helpful. -http://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2010/06/28/some-few-moments-with-the-problem-of-moments/